# Split multiallelic to biallelic in vcf by plink 1.9 and its variant name

Tags: split, bioinformatics, genetics, vcf-variant-call-format, map-files

I am trying to use [plink1.9](https://www.cog-genomics.org/plink/) to split multiallelic into biallelic. The input is that

```
1       chr1:930939:G:A 0       930939  G       A
1       chr1:930947:G:A 0       930947  A       G
1       chr1:930952:G:A;chr1:930952:G:C 0       930952  A       G
```

What it done is:

```
1       chr1:930939:G:A 0       930939  G       A
1       chr1:930947:G:A 0       930947  A       G
1       chr1:930952:G:A;chr1:930952:G:C 0       930952  A       G
1       chr1:930952:G:A;chr1:930952:G:C 0       930952  A       G
```

What I expect is:

```
1       chr1:930939:G:A 0       930939  G       A
1       chr1:930947:G:A 0       930947  A       G
1       chr1:930952:G:A 0       930952  A       G
1       chr1:930952:G:C 0       930952  A       G
```

Please help me to make a vcf or ped or map file like what I expect.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used bcftools to complete the task.

https://github.com/samtools/bcftools/issues/1193